# Is it possible to increase the dynamic range of 'External Quick Edit'?

Tags: texture-painting, external-applications

I use Tools -> External-> Quick Edit in the **Texture Paint** mode to enhance baked textures. While the renders I overlay are in 32-bit dynamic range the **Quick Edit** image is 8-bit. Is it possible to increase dynamic range of the **Quick Edit** exports into Gimp/Photoshop to 16 or 32 bits?

Comment: Not sure, but I assume this depends on the file format. For *Quick Edit* the extension is hard coded to *.png*. Here is a new operator to export the file as *exr*: https://gist.github.com/p2or/f80aff9b94645703626d, I don't have photoshop access at the moment and my Gimp version only supports 8 bit. Could you test it? As you know for sure: run the script, hit the spacebar in 3d View and type *Project Edit EXR*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @poor, your script does work for me -- I was able using your approach to create EXR file, open it in Gimp 2.9.3 and modify it using another EXR image perfectly well, however I was not successful in applying the result back so far.

Comment: Ok, great! Did you tested whether the exr has a real 32bit depth?

Comment: I got 16 float exr, which actually was my goal

Comment: nope, no cigar, final UV texture shows loss of dynamic range information

Comment: No cigar means the exr is 8bit?

Comment: Exr has correct depth, however dynamic color information [is not there](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44698/how-to-project-an-image-of-high-dynamic-range)

Answer (score 1):

I did come with a procedure which uses EXR files

### Goal

To be able to create >8 bit color depth when creating texture camera projections

### Procedure

Blender v2.7.6.2, GIMP v2.9.3

I created an [example file](https://github.com/dimus/project_image/raw/master/project_image.blend) to illustrate the workflow

- Make 32 bit texture (**UV-Tex**) for the UV texture
- Set Cycles as your renderer
- Set Output for render to OpenEXR Float(Half), RGBA
- Set lights, cameras
- Create material for your model
- Create a texture node for baking, set it to **UV-Tex**, leave active (with orange border)
- Bake
- Save result of baking to EXR file
- Clean **UV-Tex** for projection
- Select a camera, render, save result as EXR Float(half) **RENDER**
- Edit EXR to suit your needs
- Switch to 'Texture Paint Mode' Display object as 'Texture'
- You should have 'External' tab now in the toolbox in 3D view.
- In the Node view go to the texture node, and upload EXR **RENDER** file
  (This step is important, if you don't make it active in node editor, and try to project EXR image you will get "RuntimeError: Error: Image data could not be found")
- Switch Texture node back to **UV-Tex**
- In "External" menu click "Apply Camera Image" select **RENDER** file
- **UV-Tex** should have your projected EXR image now

All is working fine, however the very last step [degrades the image to 8-bit depth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44698/how-to-project-an-image-of-high-dynamic-range), even if the final file is 32 bit. I am trying to figure out if it can be fixed, and will update this post, if I'll succeed.

**ADDENDUM** The Issue had been [solved in Blender master branch](https://developer.blender.org/T47168) and high definition projections should be possible from that moment on, Thanks Campbell!