# How to project an image of high dynamic range?

Tags: texturing, external-applications

Versions: Blender 2.7.6.2, Gimp 2.9.3 (development version)

I am trying to make a texturing workflow based on using projecting images from camera to a model. In the menu in Texture mode there is an **External** tab which contains **Apply** and **Apply Camera Image**. Both of these buttons depend on `bpy.ops.paint.project_image(image=image_name)` function.

When I project a high dynamic range image, for example 16bit PNG or 16-32-floating exr onto 32 bit texture image all seems to work well. However when I save the resulting texture in Gimp and look at its histogram this is what I see:

[image: levels histogram]

It seems that in reality projected image only has 8-bit information. Is there a way to manipulate context for the `project_image` to make it output
16-32 bit dynamic range? Or may be there is another way to achieve high dynamic range projections?

### Waveforms from a [blender file example](https://github.com/dimus/project_image/raw/master/project_image.blend):

I used a the the same crop where all files had visual information.

1. Baked into 32-bit texture (EXR)

[image: Baked into 32-bit]

2. Camera render (EXR)

[image: Camera render]

3. Projection of the Camera render (also EXR)

[image: Projected Image]

Comment: Is there a .blend file which we could download to troubleshoot the steps you took to create the 32bit render?

Comment: And here is a related [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44328/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-dynamic-range-of-external-quick-edit)

Comment: As far as I know Gimp doesn't work yet at 16/32bit depth.

Comment: Development version of Gimp 2.9.3 does work with 32 bit

Comment: Don't use GIMP for that. It's a development version and it's possible that some things don't work.
Open the EXR in Blender instead and use the waveform monitor or histogram set to full sample to evaluate whether there is posterization or not.

Comment: Of course I did check if it is a Gimp problem. It is not.

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://developer.blender.org/T47168) to Blender Development

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a bug which has been solved in [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB5d45c2bf653c78928fb33548273219ef5caa5287).

Answer (score 0):

The ability to project high dynamic precision images had been added to Blender's [master branch](https://developer.blender.org/rB5d45c2bf653c78928fb33548273219ef5caa5287) by Campbell Barton. Thanks Campbell!

See the corresponding [issue](https://developer.blender.org/T47168)